# Is there a print_r or var_dump equivalent in Ruby / Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a way to dump the structure of an object, similar to the PHP functions `print_r` and `var_dump` for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The `.inspect` method of any object should format is correctly for display, just do..

```
<%= theobject.inspect %>
```

The `.methods` method may also be of use:

```
<%= theobject.methods.inspect %>
```

It may help to put that in `<pre>` tags, depending on the data

Comment: just a time saver for those looking for neater formatting in console: `puts theobject.inspect.gsub(",", "\n")`

Answer (score 68):

In views:

```
include DebugHelper

...your code...

debug(object)
```

In controllers, models, and other code:

```
puts YAML::dump(object)
```

[Source](http://source.mihelac.org/2006/3/31/ruby-rails-alternative-to-php-print_r-and-var_dump)

Comment: DebugHelper’s debug(object) raise undefined method `DebugHelper’s' :)

Answer (score 9):

In a view you can use `<%= debug(yourobject) %>` which will generate a YAML view of your data. If you want something in your log you should use `logger.debug yourobject.inspect`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use **YAML::dump** shorthand (**y**) under Rails console:

```
>> y User.first
--- !ruby/object:User 
attributes: 
  created_at: 2009-05-24 20:16:11.099441
  updated_at: 2009-05-26 22:46:29.501245
  current_login_ip: 127.0.0.1
  id: "1"
  current_login_at: 2009-05-24 20:20:46.627254
  login_count: "1"
  last_login_ip: 
  last_login_at: 
  login: admin
attributes_cache: {}

=> nil
>>
```

If you want to just preview some string contents, try using **raise** (for example in models, controllers or some other inaccessible place). You get the backtrace for free:)

```
>> raise Rails.root
RuntimeError: /home/marcin/work/github/project1
    from (irb):17
>>
```

I also really encourage you to try **ruby-debug**:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug
- http://www.sitepoint.com/article/debug-rails-app-ruby-debug/
- http://www.datanoise.com/articles/2006/7/12/tutorial-on-ruby-debug

It's incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `puts some_variable.inspect`. Or the shorter version: `p some_variable`. And for prettier output, you can use the [awesome_print gem](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print).

Answer (score 4):

Prrevious answers are great but if you don't want to use the console (terminal), in Rails you can print the result in the View by using the debug's Helper [ActionView::Helpers::DebugHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html)

```
#app/view/controllers/post_controller.rb
def index
 @posts = Post.all
end

#app/view/posts/index.html.erb
<%= debug(@posts) %>

#start your server
rails -s
```

results (in browser)

```
- !ruby/object:Post
  raw_attributes:
    id: 2
    title: My Second Post
    body: Welcome!  This is another example post
    published_at: '2015-10-19 23:00:43.469520'
    created_at: '2015-10-20 00:00:43.470739'
    updated_at: '2015-10-20 00:00:43.470739'
  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet
    attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash
      types: &5
        id: &2 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Integer
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
          range: !ruby/range
            begin: -2147483648
            end: 2147483648
            excl: true
        title: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::String
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
        body: &4 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Text
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
        published_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: &1 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime
            precision: 
            scale: 
            limit: 
        created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *1
        updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the relevant data to be displayed to stdout (the terminal output if you're running from the command line), you can use `p some_object`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this :)

```
require 'yaml'

module AppHelpers
  module Debug
    module VarDump

      class << self

        def dump(dump_object, file_path)
          File.open file_path, "a+" do |log_file|
            current_date = Time.new.to_s + "\n" + YAML::dump(dump_object) + "\n"
            log_file.puts current_date
            log_file.close
          end
        end

      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Lately I'm using **awesome_print**'s `ap` method which works on the console as well as in views.

The type-specific colored output really makes a difference if you need to visually scan for `String` or  `Numeric` objects (Although I had to tweak my stylesheet a little bit in order to get a polished look)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have become a fan of [PRY](http://pryrepl.org/), I've found it incredibly for doing things like inspecting variables, debugging running code and inspecting external code. It might be a little overkill as an answer to this specific question.